# How to group test cases in TestNG?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to launch two browsers at a time with different parameters. I've written Test suite like below. but, it is launching 8 browsers at a time (As I've mentioned parallel='tests' it is launching browsers for all classes available in that test)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="2" name="Suite" parallel="tests">
  <test name="Test1" preserve-order="true">
  <parameter name="propertyFileName" value="Constants.properties"/>
    <classes preserve-order="true">
       <class name="com.test.TestCase1"/>
       <class name="com.test.TestCase2"/>
       <class name="com.test.TestCase3"/>
       <class name="com.test.TestCase4"/>
     </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  <test name="Test2" preserve-order="true">
  <parameter name="propertyFileName" value="Constants2.properties"/>
    <classes preserve-order="true">
       <class name="com.test.TestCase5"/>
       <class name="com.test.TestCase6"/>
       <class name="com.test.TestCase7"/>
       <class name="com.test.TestCase8"/>
     </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Is there any way to launch only two browsers at a time ?

I want to group Test cases such that while running in parallel (only two test cases at a time) both should take Constants from different property file.

**EDIT-I**

TestCase1.java

```
public class TestCase1 
{

    private WebDriver driver;
    CommonMethods comObj;
    StringBuffer failureMsgs;
      @Parameters({"propertyFileName"})
      @BeforeTest
      public void beforeTest(String pname) throws Exception 
      {
          comObj=new CommonMethods(pname);
          driver=new FirefoxDriver();
          comObj.login(driver, comObj.userName,comObj.password);
      }
      @Test
      public void f() 
      {
          try
            {

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
      @AfterTest
      public void afterTest() 
      {
          System.out.println("Inside after method");
          driver.quit();
      }
}
```

Comment: If you can provide us with the java code that show us how you are starting the driver on the classes we could provide a better answer.

Comment: @amibire : I've added my test cases format.  So my requirement is Test1 classes  and Test2 classes should start with different property file and at a time two browsers only should launch.

Comment: How do you launch your tests? Can we rule out the testng.xml file being ignored?

Comment: @patrungel : I'm launching tests using testng.xml only. so, I can't ignore testng.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your setup and tear down code.  You are using @Aftertest and before test.  Your browsers would only shutdown when aftertest runs which would be only twice.  Either you should use @afterclass or @aftermethod and corresponding beforemethods.  testng is workin correctly coz it runs all your before test methods at the start, thus launching 8 browsers first.

Comment: Thank you Niharika..! After changing from BeforeTest, Aftertest to BeforeClass & AfterClass it is working. But, can you please explain little more why it is behaving like that with Beforetest & AfterTest.

Comment: BeforeTest and AfterTest run after the <test> tag that you define in your xml.  What you mark with @Test is known as Method in testng parlance